# Unable to create an instance Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager from Factory class in ZF2

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, dependency-injection, zend-framework2

I try to fetch a Doctrine Entity Manager from a Service factory but it throws an error when I do PHP unit tests, the output is:

```
    `c:\xampp\htdocs\salas\module\ApiRest\test>phpunit
PHPUnit 4.8.6 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

.....E

Time: 875 ms, Memory: 5.25Mb

There was 1 error:

1) ApiRest\Controller\SalaRestControllerTest::testGetSalaTableReturnsAnInstanceO
fSalaTable
Zend\ServiceManager\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException: Zend\ServiceManager\Serv
iceManager::get was unable to fetch or create an instance for Doctrine\ORM\Entit
yManager

...........

FAILURES!
Tests: 6, Assertions: 5, Errors: 1.`
```

This is what i'm doing: i'm trying to inject a service via DI using a Service Factory.
I register my service in module.config.php:

```
'service_manager' => array(
    'factories' => array(
        'sala-factory'=> 'ApiRest\ServiceFactory\SalaServiceFactory',
    ),
),
```

This is my service

```
class SalaService
{
    private $objectRepository;
    public function __construct(ObjectRepository $objectRepository)
    {
        $this->objectRepository= $objectRepository;         
    }    

    function listarSalas($criteria= null){
        return  $this->objectRepository->findAll();
    }

    // ...
}
```

And this is my Factory class which has the error in the $entityManager line

```
class SalaServiceFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
    {       
        $entityManager = $serviceLocator->get('Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager');
        $repository = $entityManager->getRepository('ApiRest\Entity\Sala');

        return new SalaService($repository);
    }
}
```

What would i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Did you init the ZF2 application and active the DoctrineORMModule in your PHPUnit bootstrapping code?

Comment: Yeah, It was that, I had to init DoctrineORMModule, my bad. Thanks @BramGerritsen